# Elasticsearch query timestamp difference between inner objects

Tags: elasticsearch, subquery, elasticsearch-dsl

I have a nested datatype, in which I would like to make a calculation within their inner objects, I basically want my search to return hits if they meet conditions in two inner objects, the tricky condition is to retrieve their respective timestamp values as part of the query and use them to generate the hits given a desired time difference between them.

Take this single document for example:

```
{
  "messages": [
    [
      {
        "message": "First message",
        "timeStamp": "0:00:00"
      },
      {
        "message": "Second message",
        "timeStamp": "0:10:00"
      },
      {
        "message": "Third message",
        "timeStamp": "0:15:00"
      },
      {
        "message": "Fourth message",
        "timeStamp": "0:30:00"
      },
      {
        "message": "Fifth message",
        "timeStamp": "1:00:00"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

I would like my hit to be returned if a message contains the text `Second` and the text `Third` on a different inner object is found within **5 minutes** of each other. I can easily achieve this query if I add their timeStamps directly as part of the query, but this query must run against different timeStamp data.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "nested": {
                  "path": "messages",
                  "query": {
                    "bool": {
                      "must": [
                        {
                          "match": {
                            "messages.message": "Second"
                          }
                        },
                        {
                          "match": {
                            "messages.timeStamp": "0:10:00"  <-- Start timeStamp depends on my data, consider this as a variable X to be used below
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "nested": {
                  "path": "messages",
                  "query": {
                    "bool": {
                      "must": [
                        {
                          "match": {
                            "messages.message": "Third"
                          }
                        },
                        {
                          "range": {
                            "messages.timeStamp": {
                              "gte": "0:10:00", <-- Variable X mentioned above
                              "lte": "0:15:00"  <-- I can't know end timeStamp, can only know it's a 5 minute range
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I have researched on using a result as part of a subquery, old responses under previous versions say it's not possible, and have been unable to pull it off with script_fields or inner_hits. I have also looked at Distance Feature Query but it looks like I would still need to specify an origin as part of the query, and I'm not convinced that actually resolves my need.

Would anyone know if there is a feasible way to achieve this?? Thanks!

Comment: could you please share your mapping?